# DatePicker as a readonly calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have application where the main objects have field with multiple date intervals (in a single month).

I'm looking for user-friendly way to display this data marked on a calendar, with extra colors for weekend and holidays.

I managed to setup Jquery.ui.DatePicker in inline mode .. but I don't find a way to feed it the different data ranges... to color the weekends and to mark the specific dates  like NOW, and Custom Holidays.

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker({
   inline:true,
   language:'en',
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
});
```

I tried to `setDate` .. but can not find a way to set intervals, and specify the colors or styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the classes that jQuery UI Datepicker adds to change the colours.

**For a weekend:**

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end, .ui-datepicker-week-end a.ui-state-default { 
    color: Red; 
}
```

The markup for a weekend on jQuery UI Datepicker looks like this:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="0" data-year="2015">
    <a class="ui-state-default" href="#">#DAYNUMBER</a>
</td>
```

**For specific dates and date ranges:**

***JS***

```
var SelectedDates = {};
SelectedDates[new Date("January 11, 2015")] = new Date("January 11, 2015");
SelectedDates[new Date("January 30, 2015")] = new Date("January 30, 2015");

var startDate = new Date("January 14, 2015");
var endDate = new Date("January 21, 2015");

$("input").datepicker({
   inline:true,
   language:'en',
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var holiday = SelectedDates[date];
        if (holiday) {
            return [true, "holiday", holiday];
        }
        else if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) {
            return [true, 'holiday-range', holiday];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});
```

***CSS***

```
.holiday a.ui-state-default {
   background-color: Green;
   background-image: none;
   color: White;
}

.holiday-range a.ui-state-default {
   background-color: Purple;
   background-image: none;
   color: White;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4jkk13g0/2/)

*References:* 
[show weekend](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#show-week) 
[highlight specific dates](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html)

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems.